# How to capture the error number into an variable

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have Written a code in excel vba which initially checks whether the defined word document is already open.

```
If IsFileOpen(pathh) Then
 MsgBox " Already in use"

 Else
 MsgBox "Not in use"

 End If


Function IsFileOpen(pathh As String)
   Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

   On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
   filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
   ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
   On Error Resume Next
   Open pathh For Input Lock Read As #filenum

   Close filenum          ' Close the file.
   errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
   On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

   ' Check to see which error occurred.
   Select Case errnum

       ' No error occurred.
       ' File is NOT already open by another user.
       Case 0
           IsFileOpen = False

       ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
       ' File is already opened by another user.
       Case 70
           IsFileOpen = True

       ' Another error occurred.
       Case Else
           Error errnum
    End Select
    End Function
```

But the problem is i am getting the error 70 (Permission Denied) if i have already opened the word document before running this code but it is not getting fed inside the select case code segment.

Instead it is throwing an and stops the further execution of the code after.

```
   Open pathh For Input Lock Read As #filenum
```

[image]

I want to capture the error number and feed it to inside the select case where it will display the appropriate message whether the file is opened or not

Comment: `errnum = Err.Number`

Comment: but the code execution stops before assigning the errnum, it is throwing the error message (Which i have shown above )and doesn't continue the execution. Although i have mentioned "On Error Resume Next" at the beginning of the method, but still its not going to the next step

Comment: You have to trap errors with an On Error statement otherwise the runtime will take over. Do that and you have access to the error object.

Comment: Is your VBE set to break on all errors (Tools - Options, General tab)? BTW your second `On Error Resume Next` statement will clear the error so you need to remove that.

Comment: Update, you just changed the code to uncomment the On Error Resume Next. That gives you the access but inline, better to branch to an error handler in my view.

Comment: @Rory - yes it is set to "Break on All Errors" do i need to change it ? and yes i removed the second "On Error Resume Next" statement

Comment: Yes - otherwise none of your error handlers will have any effect.

Comment: @Rory thank you, changed the selection from Break on ALL errors to Break on Unhandled Errors, and its working fine.